# Securing RabbitMQ messages

Tags: c#, security, rabbitmq

I'm looking for some advice here.
I have build a multi tenancy solution using RabbitMQ in C#.
It consists of a cloud solution that is pushing messages to the client applications through RabbitMQ.
Routing for RabbitMQ is setup using a routing key like: `myapp.messagestream.<customercode>`

All clients connect to RabbitMQ using **the same username and password**. Although the client code is obfuscated, it is still relatively simple to obtain the username and password. With this, theoratically, one could "guess" any other customer id and get the stream. Obviously, this is not what we want.

The way I would like to address this is to encrypt all messages using a encryption key per customer. This way, even if you have the username and password for RabbitMQ and you guessed a correct customer id, you would still not see any usable information.

Could anyone please share there insight on the above? Does it seem to be a good idea? or am I completely gone out of my mind?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always thought that AMQP is intended for Cluster internal messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the message is encrypted, it'd be consumed and removed from the queue. I guess that's not something you want to allow.

Consider creating different users and allowing them to read only from their own queues through [authorization](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authorisation). You can connect it to a LDAP.

EDIT:
Hiding the messages in transit is always a good idea, but that can be achieved with SSL/TLS, no need to add another layer on top of that

Comment: That it is being removed from the queue is not a problem I think. The way things are currently setup is that messages have a TTL of 2 seconds after which they are classified as no longer valid. SSL/TLS has already been taken care of. The only thing I was worrying about was when somebody would use the credentials and use a wildcard in the routing key. Indeed, the best way would be to have user accounts created for each connection, but this might potentially lead to thousands of users. Would that not impose a problem?

Comment: @Mekroebo I've never set up more than a dozen users (and I've done it statically), but if the sessions are long enough, I don't think it'd be a problem. You can test it with LDAP, which requires only configuration, and move to more tailored solutions if it does not suit your needs (maybe try the HTTP authorization backend before moving to encrypting the messages), IMHO I'd try first the options that are provided by RMQ directly

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late for my own party but here's what I have done:

The client application already authenticated itself to an API which then issued an JWT.
I added come claims to the token (topics) for RabbitMQ and enabled the JWT authentication plugin.
Now, when a client authenticates to RabbitMQ with this JWT it is only granted access to the topics defined in the JWT.